# Error in function to open any application with AutoHotKey

Tags: function, autohotkey

I am trying to make a function to open any application but I get the message below.
What do I need tochange to make it work?

```
+!n:: openAPP("notepad.exe")

openAPP(appName)
{
    StringCaseSense, On
    Process, Exist, %appName%
    if ErrorLevel
    {   
        if WinExist("ahk_exe " . %appName%)
        {
            WinActivate, ahk_exe %appName%
        }          
    }
    else
    {
        Run %appName%
    }
    return
}
```

[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change
`if WinExist("ahk_exe " . %appName%)`
to
`if WinExist("ahk_exe " . appName)`

Without using the `%%` around `appName` .

**Functions** can take expressions as parameters and there is no need to enclose the variable name with %%. For **commands** on the other hand you have to enclose the variable name with %% in order to retrieve the value stored in that variable.

For example, in your script:
`WinExist()` is a **function** and you would use it as noted above:
`WinExist("ahk_exe " . appName)`

`WinActivate` is a **command** and you must use the %% (as you correctly do):
`WinActivate, ahk_exe %appName%`